# CodeKit 2: .less file doesn't compile because bootstrap mixins not found

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, codekit

I am new to CodeKit 2 and I don't get my workflow up and running.

The problem is that I want to use the .make-row() and .make-sm-column() mixins and then CodeKit compiles the file and says:

```
// Error in Codekit
SyntaxError: variable @grid-gutter-width is undefined


// .less file
.logo {
    .make-sm-column(12);
}
```

I worked with Yeoman for a while and had no problems with that syntax.

Comment: looks like you're not including the appropriate files. check the properties of whatever file you expect to be including the mixins

Comment: ohh shooot! I included the .css bootstrap file instead of the .less